# In a PyQt5 application, is it possible to run sklearn with parallel jobs without freezing

Tags: scikit-learn, pyqt, multiprocessing, qthread, joblib

Is it possible to run, in a qt application, without freezing the gui, let's say a [sklearn gird search](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) that use several jobs parallel (`n_jobs > 1`)? The problem is that joblib that is used for parallelizing sklearn code cannot run multiprocess into a thread.

For example, I'm using Gridsearch to find the best parameters for a svr, which is quite computionnaly intensive.

This question has been asked several times, but no solution found:

[pyqt5-run-sklearn-calculations-on-a-separate-qthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286339/pyqt5-run-sklearn-calculations-on-a-separate-qthread), suggest the use of `QProcess` ?

[multiprocessing-backed-parallel-loops-cannot-be-nested-below-threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646052/multiprocessing-backed-parallel-loops-cannot-be-nested-below-threads),the `threading.current_thread().name = 'MainThread'` workaround does not work after the issue [has been fixed](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/180)

[joblib-parallel-uses-only-one-core-if-started-from-qthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307132/joblib-parallel-uses-only-one-core-if-started-from-qthread), rewrite the task using `multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)`. This method is not applicable for gridsearch embed njobs.

[use sklearn cross validation train, in PyQt button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50506566/5547936), No aswers...

And any insight why this is **purposely** not supported (it a [feature](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/180#issuecomment-149249514)) ? It seems like it something that would be quite useful ?

Comment: I am not an expert in scikit learn but I work a lot with pyqt and relate it to Qt, I could try to give you a solution but I do not want to learn to use *scikit learn* now, you could provide the script (with the appropriate entries and complete imports) to avoid that work.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the issue, the problem resides with the default backend used by `joblib`, namely `loky`.

After some digging through the [joblib](https://www.tutorialdocs.com/tutorial/joblib/parallel.html) and [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.register_parallel_backend.html) documentation, I resolved my issue by switching the `joblib` backend to `threading`.  Note, the call to `register_parallel_backend` lies outside the `__init__` function.

```py
from sklearn.utils import parallel_backend, register_parallel_backend
from joblib._parallel_backends import ThreadingBackend

class ModelTrainer(QRunnable):
    register_parallel_backend('threading', ThreadingBackend, make_default=True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Yes but threading it no the same type of parallelization. At the end, I chose to use dask instead. Working well with sklearn, with different processes.